# Sending ipa to testers without a distribution file (just with provisioning file)

Tags: iphone, ios

Today I was building an ipa from my application to send to testers. I have always thought that i would need a distribution provisioning file for this but a friend of mine came with his ipod and I just added his device to the provisioning file and rebuild the ipa file. After syncing his device against my itunes library he was able to play/test the game without problem. So, why is then needed a distribution ad-hoc file?

Does this work because I installed it in the computer that owns the provisioning file? I'm a bit messed up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of distribution. One is Ad-hoc, the other is Enterprise Distribution.

Ad-hoc limits your distribution to 100 devices. It means that for your development certificate, you cannot test your app in more than 100 devices during the certificates life. Also, ad-hoc requires you to physically connect the device to the computer and build the app. This most-likely looks like the situation that you are in.

Enterprise Distribution (ED) is the other way. ED lets you host the app on a secure web-server. This way, you can just copy the ipa on a webserver and pass the link to your colleagues. They will be able to download the app on to their devices directly by pressing the `itms://` link (that you send them), without having to be around you.

If you have your options open, I would also check [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). It is a third party app distribution system.

Comment: There are a few inconsistencies, the devices are tied to the Development Provisioning Profile, not the certificate. Also the Developer Account itself is tied to 100 devices in total and deleted devices are still included in that 100 device total. Apple do allow a chance each year on renewal to remove old devices and make way for new ones.

Also for TestFlight, you'd still need to generate a Provisioning Profile with the relevant testers devices added. It just makes it easier to grab UUID's from testers and send beta versions to download directly via email

Comment: From apple documentation on the developer center I read this for ad-hoc distribution: "Ad Hoc distribution allows you to share your application with up to 100 iPhone, iPad or iPod touch users, and to distribute your application through email or by posting it to a web site or server.". So, it seems I will be able to distribute through a web server, etc... with this option. Am I missing something?